# framework7 selecting .page-on-center and not page-on-left

Tags: html-framework-7

I have weird bug, when i select something Iam getting .page-on-left items but not .page-on-center. I cant select $$('.page-on-center') for some reason. soo can someone help me ? what to do. how to set always to select elements in $$('.page-on-center'),...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per hierarchy, page-on-left element comes before the page-on-center element, thus things getting selected with page-on-left by default.
You may add following parameters in the app initialization.

`var myApp = new Framework7({
    swipeBackPage: false,
    preloadPreviousPage: false
});`

it will actually remove page-on-left element so that only page-on-center will remain.